# Как установить на ноутбук с запароленным BIOS-ом и со слетевшим Windows-ом новую операционку?

Tags: железо, bios, ос

Помогите разобраться, как можно установить на ноутбук с запароленным BIOS-ом и со слетевшим Windows-ом новую операционку. Из-за потери пароля на BIOS-е, нельзя поменять порядок загрузки устройств.

Comment: А может есть утилита от производителя, пере-прошивающая биос. После самой операции пере-прошивки пароль должен слететь.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Это ноутбук, а не мат. плата. Куча специфики. Хотя бы даже разобрать ноутбук сложнее.
2. Раз БИОС запаролен, то нужно разобраться как эта защита устроена.
3. Сбросом CMOS можно сделать только хуже, поэтому см. п.2. В частности, так на IBM-Lenovo. Т.к. есть пароль на изменение настроек BIOS'а, а есть пароль на загрузку. И при сбросе CMOS может самопроизвольно установится пароль на загрузку системы. А после этого - снятие ТОЛЬКО на специализированном оборудовании.
4. Можно попробовать несколько раз ввести произвольный пароль. Многие ноутбуки взамен выдают challenge-код, по которому с помощью специальной утилиты сотрудники сервис-центра могут сгенерировать подходящий пароль (ну, например, из-за наличия хэш-коллизий или просто бэкдур - мастер-пароль для сброса). Дураков, которые сделали бы полную блокировку, нет :-) Кстати, у некоторых ноутбуков (SONY) challenge-код генерируется разный при каждой загрузке. И обычно счетчик неправильно введенных паролей сбрасывается после цикла выключение-включение. Так что попыток существенно больше 3-х :-)
5. У каждого типа ноутбуков свой алгоритм сброса пароля. Поэтому самый простой метод - обратиться в сервис-центр. Если хотите разобраться сами - придется искать информацию по крупицам, т.к. снятие паролей это коммерческий секрет.
6. Действительно, можно подсунуть загрузочный диск, а винчестер отформатировать. Ну, или записать на винчестер загрузчик типа GRUB, который сможет загрузиться с нужного Вам носителя.
7. ВНИМАНИЕ! Наряду с паролем на БИОС зачастую устанавливается пароль на жесткий диск! И как следствие - при подключении его к настольному компьютеру ничего хорошего не произойдет. Скорее всего - данные будут просто недоступны. Снятие пароля с жесткого диска в домашних условиях практически нереально. Но если повезет, то есть списки заводских мастер-паролей, с помощью которых в худшем раскладе можно винчестер распаролить, но с потерей данных, которые на нем были.
8. Можно попытаться перешить BIOS. НО! Есть области в нем, которые при стандартной перешивке не перешиваются. Но идея достойна рассмотрения, если удастся найти секретные ключи по перешивке всего содержимого микросхемы flash, включая области DMI/Escd и паролей.

Comment: Из ваших ответов для меня подходят только два:
1. отформатировать хард
2. использовать загрузчик типа GRUB
нужно эти испробовать - другое пробовалось безрезультатно.
Спасибо господа!

Comment: Ноутбук HP Compaq 6730s.При включении ноутбука загружается Windos XP,
но работает чересчур медленно и часто зависает. Из-за пароля на BIOSe
нельзя поменять прежние настройки

Comment: Самый простой способ войти в boot меню, если не удалось, то фокус с винтом остается, а дальше от безысходности - программный сброс CMOS, аппаратный сброс CMOS (джампер), батарейка... @gecube расширишь последовательность?

Answer (score 3):

Материнка новая? помнится когда-то решал проблемы с биосом следующим образом:

- были стандартные пароли, которые подходили к определенным типам биоса (нужно знать название биоса и иногда его версию)
- вытаскивали батарейку ждали 10-20 минут, биос сбрасывался (помниться даже шаманили замыкая отверткой + и - у слота батарейки, тогда конденсаторы быстрее сбрасывались - не знаю насколько это правда :) )
- на материнской плате есть джампер, который ставишь в определенное положение (см. инструкцию к материнке), включаешь, ждешь пару секунд (комп не загружается), выключаешь, возвращаешь его в предыдущее положение, загружаешься - биос сброшен
- ну или вытащить винчестер, отформатировать его на другом компе, так чтобы с него нельзя было загрузиться, когда, по порядку определенному в биосе, дело дойдет до CD -  поставить операционнку.

Comment: 1. ---

2. сомневаюсь. я как то сутки ждал не помогло. Потом только цузнал про джампер :)

3. хз, есть ли он на ноутбуке, да и разбирать его удовольствие еще то

кстати у некоторых бисово что бы загрузиться с другого устройства и в биос захолдить не нада ... вроде F8. и появляется менюшка с какого устройства грузится

Comment: у меня на стационарном компе F11 для выбора устройства с которого грузиться

Comment: вот ссылка http://smanuals.ru/electronics-repair/hp-compaq-6730s-6735s-disassembly-replace-cooling-fan.html как разбирать Ваш ноутбук   , а на вот этой фотографии http://smanuals.ru/files/Image/articles/hp-compaq-6730s-6735s-disassembly-replace-cooling-fan/pic18.jpg четко видна батарейка, ну или если Вам более приемлем вариант с винчестером, то в этом же howto Вы найдете как его достать

Comment: Еще раз - совет вытащить батарейку бессмысленен.<p>
1. Есть две батарейки - АКБ и батарейка CMOS. Понятно, что обе подпитывают содержимое CMOS. Ну, а если есть питание от адаптера - то и от него тоже. Ну, и при разборке ЗУ и АКБ нужно отключать!<p>
2. Пароль в ноутбуках, а тем более корпоративных хранится не в CMOS, а в BIOS. В изменяемой его области. Так что сброс CMOS'а не поможет<p>
3. Максимум в CMOS'е может лежать флаг наличия пароля, но для многих ноутбуков по умолчанию после сброса CMOS флаг означает "пароль установлен".<p>

Comment: 4. CMOS работает как конденсатор. Т.е. просто вытащить батарейку и подождать - не поможет. Т.к. заряд будет стекать дооооолго. Если же замкнуть контакты батарейки CMOS - тоже не лучший вариант, т.к. как там реализована схемотехника фиг его знает, но правильный метод сброса, как заметил GLAGOLA, найти площадку JRST или аналогичную и замкнуть ее. Это так же может быть отдельный джампер или сброс CMOS'а может быть выведен на отдельный DIP-switch.<p>
5. CMOS "сбросить" можно софтовым путем. Грузим утилиту типа Uniflash и говорим "destroy cmos data". Контрольная сумма CMOS слетает - он сбрасываетс

Comment: Далее - на некоторых ноутбуках батарейка CMOS может быть впаять, а не быть на разъеме. Ну, и это может быть не батарейка CMOS, а маленький аккумуляторчик. Заряжающийся в процессе работы ноутбука.